# Should Monero start using MIPs(Monero Implementation Protocol) similar to Bitcoin(BIPs)?

Tags: development, development-roadmap

It might be a little early and Monero is still young, but should we in the future start making our own MIPs?

Comment: I don't know if it exactly relates to what you say but Monero got a research lab were academics publish "MRL" see https://lab.getmonero.org

Answer (score 5):

Once a project starts to gain significant traction, like having its own research lab papers, it's ready to have a formal improvement process.

The BIP ("Bitcoin Improvement Process") was introduced by Amir Taaki back in the early days of Bitcoin and was inspired by the PIP ("Python Improvement Process"). Consequently having the MIP ("Monero Improvement Process") is a great step towards a structured approach to improving the protocol that each Monero client would implement.

Clearly the MRL (Monero Research Labs) papers are just one (very strong) initiator for a MIP. An MRL paper would provide deep technical analysis and requirements that the MIP would then implement. However other initiators could come about through community feedback.

In each case I'd see the MIP as being the second (more developer accessible) layer so that the community can provide further discussion and acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

The governance structure [described here](https://getmonero.org/2016/02/10/monero-missive-2015-year-in-review.html) details a rough way in which Monero is improved, though it isn't formalized in any sort of MIP-type structure.